# The Use of Law of Iterated Expectations in this example.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am reading an solution to a problem, and I came across a expression:

$$E[X_{k+1}|X_{k}]=aX_{k}$$,

Where $$X_{k}$$ is the random variables of a series of trials.

The solution says that "by using the law of iterated expectations, we obtained

$$E[X_{k+1}]=aE[X_{k}]$$

So, I went to check what the Law of Iterated Expectation is, and I saw

$$E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$$,

But I don't see how I can apply this law to

$$E[X_{k+1}|X_{k}]=aX_{k}$$,

How is the above derivation done? I don't see any connection....

Answer (score 0):

Take expectation on both sides of $E(X_{k+1}|X_k)=aX_k$. You  get $EX_{k+1}=EX_k$. You are just applying the Law of Iterated Expectation with $X=X_{k+1}$ and $Y=X_k$ and the fact that $EaX_k=aEX_k$.

Comment: Thank you. I see.

Comment: @AmosKu After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).